# Handling schema evolution in reading avro data from GCP PubSub in Dataflow using apache beam

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, avro, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a GCP Dataflow streaming job. This read avro encoded data from PubSub and writes to GCS bucket in parquet format. The avro schema I have used has now evolved with additional field in it with backward compatibility. Now the problem is, I want to read both version 1 and version 2 data from PubSub in same Dataflow job. How can this be achieved in Dataflow written using apache beam.

```
Example 
version 1
    record Emp {
        string name;
        string age;
    }

version 2
    record Emp {
        string name;
        string age;
        union {null , Address} address = null;
    }

    record Address {
        string pin;
        string city;
    }
```

Pipeline code, here Emp schema is from version 2 and data that is coming to pipeline is of version 1.

```
PCollection<GenericRecord> stream = pipeline
    .apply("Read avro from PubSub",
        PubsubIO.readAvroGenericRecords(Emp.getClassSchema()).fromSubscription(options.getSubscription()))
    .setCoder(AvroCoder.of(Emp.getClassSchema()));
```

Error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Forbidden IOException when reading from InputStream
        org.apache.beam.sdk.util.CoderUtils.decodeFromSafeStream(CoderUtils.java:121)
        org.apache.beam.sdk.util.CoderUtils.decodeFromByteArray(CoderUtils.java:101)
        org.apache.beam.sdk.util.CoderUtils.decodeFromByteArray(CoderUtils.java:95)
        org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.pubsub.PubsubIO.lambda$parsePayloadUsingCoder$839baa85$1(PubsubIO.java:1297)
        org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.Contextful.lambda$fn$36334a93$1(Contextful.java:112)
        org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.MapElements$1.processElement(MapElements.java:143)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
        org.apache.avro.io.DirectBinaryDecoder.readInt(DirectBinaryDecoder.java:110)
        org.apache.avro.io.BinaryDecoder.readIndex(BinaryDecoder.java:493)
        org.apache.avro.io.ResolvingDecoder.readIndex(ResolvingDecoder.java:282)
        org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readWithoutConversion(GenericDatumReader.java:187)
        org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:160)
        org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readField(GenericDatumReader.java:259)
        org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readRecord(GenericDatumReader.java:247)
        org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readWithoutConversion(GenericDatumReader.java:179)
        org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:160)
        org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:153)
        org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.AvroCoder.decode(AvroCoder.java:373)
        org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.Coder.decode(Coder.java:159)
        org.apache.beam.sdk.util.CoderUtils.decodeFromSafeStream(CoderUtils.java:118)
        org.apache.beam.sdk.util.CoderUtils.decodeFromByteArray(CoderUtils.java:101)
        org.apache.beam.sdk.util.CoderUtils.decodeFromByteArray(CoderUtils.java:95)
        org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.pubsub.PubsubIO.lambda$parsePayloadUsingCoder$839baa85$1(PubsubIO.java:1297)
        org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.Contextful.lambda$fn$36334a93$1(Contextful.java:112)
        org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.MapElements$1.processElement(MapElements.java:143)
        org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.MapElements$1$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:232)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.processElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:191)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn.processElement(SimpleParDoFn.java:339)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:44)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:49)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.runReadLoop(ReadOperation.java:212)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.start(ReadOperation.java:163)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.MapTaskExecutor.execute(MapTaskExecutor.java:92)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.process(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:1437)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.access$1100(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:165)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker$7.run(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:1113)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Please clarify your issue. Do you have schema verification on pubsub and wants to read 2 schema types in the same topic or it is an issue on your dataflow job ? Try to complement you question with error messages, diagram of you pipeline and snippets you want to change, please.

Comment: @ewertonvsilva We don't have schema in pubsub. I have edited it snippets and errors.

Comment: I'm not sure how you are defining the schema file, but keep in mind that schema compatibility has to follow some rules, just adding new fields isn't enough. For your specific case you want to achieve a backwards compatible schema you have to, 
- add optional fields **or** add mandatory fields with a meaningful default value. So the address have to have a default value, or be optional.

Comment: You need to modify your schema to allow both your old and new message types. You can do this with optionals.